# Javascript blob createObjectURL not showing results

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob

I am currently trying to convert a rather large canvas (1920x1080) to a blob. Making it viewable and downloadable for the user.
I first used `toDataURI` but that didn't really work either because the canvas is way to big and detailed for that (Atleast I assume).
I now mananged to create the blob but without succes of actually copying any of the content of the canvas. I am currently using the following code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector(".test-screenshot")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function f(arg)
{ var y = document.createElement("img") || new Image();
  y.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(y, 0, 0) };
  y.src = arg
}

for (var i=0; i<elm.length; i++)
    f(elm[i].m._images[elm[i].m._value])

// At this point the previously created canvas is filled correctly.

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var newImg = document.createElement("img"),
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    newImg.onload = function() {
        // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }; 

    newImg.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(newImg)
});
```

I started working on my own first but never succeeded and currently still fail with the MDN example.

I do always end up with the following url which I assume is good:

`blob:http://localhost/2b216f91-4326-4df2-9c71-1c8d5e4c3dad`

If anyone could please point out what I am missing?

Comment: That doesn't look like a blob url. I thought blob urls started with `blob://` and had no hostname...

Comment: Apologies, I missed out the `blob:` when pasting it. It does load the `png` image succesfully but shows a blank image meaning nothing has been transfered.

Comment: Image loading is async. You need to wait until image has loaded+drawn, then use toBlob() (f() is never called either in this example). toBlob also needs a mime-type argument.

Comment: Forgot to change something. `f()` is being called right now. After the `for` the canvas looks like this: http://a.pomf.se/slrupj.png (meaning it has succeeded placing the arguments on the canvas). After that the toBlob is being called.

Comment: Forcing the "jpeg" MIME will paste a black image with no content due to lack of a transparency map. Forcing "png" (default) will paste a transparent image with nothing in it.

Comment: Just because the image shows in canvas does not mean it shows at the right *time*. It's extremely likely the image is drawn *after* toBlob is called... you need to call toBlob from the onload handler. But since you have several images loaded this will not work either... you need an image loader to load all images, when loaded, draw the to canvas, then use toBlob.